# How can I create a flashable rom from a configured tablet?

Tags: rom-flashing

We have a fully configured android tablet. I need to create many more just like it. What is the easiest way to do this? Ideally I would create a rom which I could just flash in one step. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have custom recovery installed?

Comment: Related: [Clone android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22631/clone-android-device/22635#22635)

Comment: I do... I am running CM9 rom.. Christian Troy's build. With CWM

Comment: That's a good link and quite a bit better than the current set of steps. But I would like to get it down to something so simple a non-tech person could do it in a couple easy to follow steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all other tablets are of identical model to the original, it should be as easy as rooting them, installing CWM, and then restoring the Nandroid backup you made with the original one.

Keep in mind that Nandroid utility does not back up the contents of the SD Card.  If duplicating the SD Card is also required, that would need to be done separately.