# Clone and distribute Android 4 device with preloaded applications

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backup, multiple-devices

This may be related to [Clone Android Device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22631/12373) but I don't think it fits my need. I'm looking to accomplish something similar to [Sysprep for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824816.aspx), which would allow me to distribute Android devices with preloaded applications and settings, such as:

1. Intitial data, settings, and connection information
2. Preloaded applications, with proper licenses/keys for non-free applications
3. addon / restriction for users

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Restoring a Nandroid backup does solve your problem. Though the source from which the Nandroid backup and the targets on which they are applied are to be same brand and model.

Comment: yes they are to be same brand and model, I saw there issue with IMEI and activations keys,

Comment: FYI: Google just added a [private channel](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.de/2012/12/google-play-private-channel-your-own.html) to their play store. I guess more corporate features will come after they took care of the [consumer market](http://mobile.bloomberg.com/news/2012-12-12/google-chairman-says-android-winning-mobile-war-with-apple-tech.html).

Comment: @ce4 probably:-), will be better to convert your commnent to answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You would easily be able to do this via a nandroid backup, and there a apps on Google Play that allow you to restrict the device.

The only issue is licenses for apps - they are linked to the Google Account, so you would have to use the same Google Account on every device if you don't want to pay for every app for each Google Account on every device.

This is fine if it is a generic account, but it may not be wanted if it is a personal account.

If you make a nandroid backup with all the apps, and then restore it to all the other devices, it will have the apps, settings and licenses, as well as the Google Account.

I am going to check on Google Play for the app that allows you to limit ability (I know there is at least one).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make your own ROM using a existing one and add more stuff to it. This site would have helped you http://romkitchen.org/ but its now down.

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246) contains more info, including links to more tools.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to mod but just have some sort of mobile device rollout management for a series of maybe corporate devices.

Comment: @ce4 partially agreed :-)