# Bulk Android Device Provisioning

Tags: customization, multiple-devices

I'm working for a company that wants to hand out 1000's of Android tablets with a bunch of OS customisations, i.e. specific preinstalled apps, default home page, amongst other things.

What solutions are available to achieve this (without having to go through each device manually)?

Ideally, if there were a mechanism to create an Android OS image that could be deployed to all devices during manufacturing process, that'd be perfect.

**Edit:** I'm not looking for a MDM solution for enterprise, just a one hit preinstall of apps/settings during device manufacturing/setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up and install non play store apps to multiple devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116084/set-up-and-install-non-play-store-apps-to-multiple-devices)

Comment: This sounds like something you'd need to talk to the manufacturer about.

Comment: Related: [how to do bulk updates across multiple devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/123902/16575) / [Can I set up one android phone, create a backup and restore it in multiple phones?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/106745/16575) / [Centrally managing large number of android tablets](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102106/16575) / [centrally manage corporate android devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/92036/16575) / [Best Practise for deploying a 'clone' image across 200 android tablets](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65140/16575)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the suggested question. A one-off run of several thousand devices has completely different needs to setting up a handful each day.

Comment: More related: [Clone and distribute Android 4 device with preloaded applications](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32687/16575) / [Clone Android Device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22631/16575). Make your pick :) Please check them out and then point out which of them fit or why none of them fit (whichever the result will be).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, in the end, the manufacturer of the tablets is providing the customisations at the point of manufacture.